# Random Variable with non-decreasing function - Inclusion

Tags: random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable and $f$ a non-decreasing function on the range of $X$. If $Y=f(X)$, then
$$\{X\le q\}\subset\{Y\le f(q)\} \quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad \{X<q\}\supset\{Y<f(q)\}$$
for any $q\in\mathbb R$.

How can one see these inclusions?

---

I've tried the following approach. We can write 
$$\{X\le q\}=X^{-1}\left((-\infty,q]\right)\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad \{Y\le f(q)\}=X^{-1}(f^{-1}((-\infty,f(q)]))$$
Now if I could show that $(-\infty,q]\subset f^{-1}((-\infty,f(q)])$, then the first inclusion would follow, but I am struggling to see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $ x \le q \Rightarrow f(x) \le f(q)$ thus $\omega \in [X(\omega)\le q] \Rightarrow \omega \in [Y(\omega)\le f(q)]$.
2. $f(x) <f(q)  \Rightarrow x<q$ thus $\omega \in [Y(\omega)<f(q)] \Rightarrow \omega \in [X(\omega)<q]$.